# Should I set iOS deployment target to lower version than iOS versions of the devices I have?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have some iOS devices.
But all iOS versions of them are 5.1.1.
So I can't test my app in iOS 5.0.x.

Should I set the iOS deployment target to 5.0?
Is it safe to assume that apps will run properly in iOS 5.0 if it runs properly in iOS 5.1?

Or should I set it to 5.1.1 which I can test in?

And if I set it to 5.1.1, how will my app be displayed in iTunes Store to people whose devices are iOS 5.0?
The app will not be displayed to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From 5.1 to 5.0 the only important API change is the ability to use Siri to enter text in `UITextField` and other text containers.

You'll probably be safe setting it to 5.0

Comment: thanks for useful information. i will set my deployment target to 5.0.

Answer (score 1):

Our stats show that most people on some version of 5 are on 5.1.1. However if you want to test for 5.0, it is possible to download the 5.0 Simulator.

Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads -> Components Tab -> Install 5.0 Simulator